# How to update Prestashop product state programically?

Tags: php, prestashop

I trying to learn PS and i want to simple update all Prestsahop products state by external script.

I have something like this to disable all products by the supplier (example):

```
<?php

include(dirname(__FILE__).'/config/config.inc.php');
include(dirname(__FILE__).'/init.php');

$default_lang = Configuration::get('PS_LANG_DEFAULT');
$product = new Product();
if ($product->id_supplier = 2) {
    $product->active = 0;
    $product->update();
}
```

But it failed throwing PrestaShopDatabaseException

Comment: can you mention full error line?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you create a new product and don't fill the required fields. If you want to change the existing product you need to set its id during a product object creation.
So your code should be like

```
$product = new Product($id_product, true, $default_lang); // if you want to get certain language, if ont skip the last parameter

if ($product->id_supplier = 2) {
    $product->active = 0;
    $product->update();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

as i understood you want to disable all products for a specific supplier

first you want to get list of all product ids from table ps_product in database. then instantiate a product object by each id_product and disable it if it has the id_supplier condition that you mentioned

```
require(dirname(__FILE__).'/../config/config.inc.php');

// getting list of product_id
$product_ids = Db::getInstance()->executeS('select id_product from ps_product');

foreach($product_ids as $item) {
    $product = new Product($item['id_product']);
    if ($product->id_supplier == 2) {
        $product->active = false;
        $product->update();
    }
}
```